# Why is this loop becoming infinite when using String.valueOf or Float.toString?

Tags: java, string, floating-point, infinite-loop

I am reading in bytes from a file using a `FileInputStream`. The code (in its correct form) is as follows:

```
String s = "";
try {
        File file = new File(...);
        FileInputStream file_input = new FileInputStream(file);
        DataInputStream data_in = new DataInputStream(file_input );

        while (true) {
            try {
                for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
                    byteArray[index] = data_in.readByte();
                }         
            } catch (EOFException eof) {
                break;
            }

            float f = readFloatLittleEndian(byteArray); // transforms 4 bytes into a float
            //s += Float.toString(f); <- here's the problem 
        }
        data_in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }
}
System.out.print(s);
```

If I run this code as is, then the loop finishes when reading all of the file and transforming each set of 4 `bytes` into a `float`.

However, if I uncomment that line, the file never finishes, and seems to loop through the file over and over. Also, printing `f` (without using `Float.toString` or `String.valueOf`) will not turn this into an infinite loop.

Comment: What evidence do you have that it is an infinite loop (rather than just slow)?

Comment: I include a counter of the file's size and incrementing that counter the number of times the loop executes. If the counter is larger than that size, I reset it to zero and output another counter showing how many times this has happened. When I do this, it prints 1 2 3 4 ... and does not stop.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `catch (EOFException eof)` with `catch (Exception e)`, just for debugging purpose? (maybe another Exception is thrown)

Comment: I tried this, but nothing important. However, commenting the offending line out (and printing the stack trace) only gives an `EOFException`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you try [this](http://pastebin.com/TTR2hWhg) and see if it has any effect?

Comment: I actually tested this just before you commented. Yep, it finishes this time. I guess `Float.toString` is extremely slow (many times slower) compared to `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @user473973 It's not `Float.toString` - I'll explain it in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop does not become infinite - just grossly inefficient. The problem with the `+=` on `java.lang.String` is that it produces a new immutable object, discarding the one that it held before. Each time it makes a copy, making the process an O(n<sup>2</sup>) in terms of the number of entries in your file.

The fix is straightforward - replace `String s` with `StringBuilder s`, and use `append` in place of `+=`.

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
try {
    File file = new File(...);
    FileInputStream file_input = new FileInputStream(file);
    DataInputStream data_in = new DataInputStream(file_input );
    while (true) {
        try {
            for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
                byteArray[index] = data_in.readByte();
            }         
        } catch (EOFException eof) {
            break;
        }
        float f = readFloatLittleEndian(byteArray); // transforms 4 bytes into a float
        s.append(f); 
    }
    data_in.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println(e.toString());
}
System.out.print(s);
```

Comment: Another example that String concatenation does not live in a vacuum, and does affect performance. Thanks!